# Error messages in searchbar

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredfarger.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
```

Here I get the error

> "Immutable value of type '[(String)]' only has mutating members named
>   'removeAll'"

```
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.TitleList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredfarger = array as! [String]
```

Here I get the error:

> "Cannot assign 'filteredfarger' in 'self'

```
 self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Could you add to your question the declaration of property `self.filteredfarger`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that filteredfarger is immutable. Did you define it using 'let' or 'var' ?

An excellent tutorial for searchBar can be found here:
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift